# $\int_{C_a} dz/z = \mbox{Log} \ a$ - how to show rigorously?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

Let $a \in  D \equiv (\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R_{\le0}})$ and let $C_a$ be a curve contained in $D$ connecting $1$ and $a$. Show that $$\int_{C_a} \frac{dz}{z} = \mbox{Log} \ a.$$

I'm having trouble with such exercises because I don't know what I can assume. I'm guessing the idea is to assume the FTC, and show that $\mbox{Log} z \equiv \ln |z| + i \mbox{Arg} z$ is the primitive of $1/z$. To that end, I would check it's analytic apart from $0$, then by C-R show that $$\frac{d\mbox{Log} z}{dz} = \frac{1}{z}.$$

Is this a complete solution? I would want to be as rigorous as possible.

Comment: First step: $D$ is simply connected, and $\frac1z$ is holomorphic on $D$, hence $F(a) = \int_{C_a}\frac{dz}{z}$ is independent of the choice of $C_a$. Second step, $F'(a) = \frac1a$. Third step, $F(1) = 0$, conclude that $e^{F(z)} = z$, and thus $F(z) = \operatorname{Log} z$.

Comment: Stuck on the second step - obviously I can't evaluate the integral directly on some fixed path, like a line segment from 1 to $a$ (since it runs into the problem of a complex log again, even with a $t$-parametrization). So I tried differentiation under the integral sign. I almost got the answer (I got $1/a(a-1)$, apparently I failed to cancel something, will redo the calculation). Is this the right approach? What annoys me is that I can't use a simpler contour (I used a line segment from $1$ to $a$, assuming for the moment a not neg. real), because otherwise (for example first vertically up to

Comment: $\Im a$, then horizontally to $\Im a + \Re a$) there is a problem since I get two integrals dependent only on the real/imaginary parts of $a$, so I can't differentiate that under the integral.

Comment: By the independence of the path, you have $F(z) - F(z_0) = \int_{[z_0,z]} \frac{dz}{z}$, where the integral is over the line segment connecting $z_0$ and $z$. So $$\frac{F(z)-F(z_0)}{z-z_0} - \frac{1}{z_0} = \frac{1}{z-z_0}\int_{[z_0,z]}\left(\frac1z - \frac{1}{z_0}\right)\,dz$$